# neo4j - endless query

Tags: neo4j, cypher, py2neo

i have a question related to neo4j and bulkimport.
i wrote a cypher query and it doesnt work and takes alot of time until it crashes. 
I insert this statment via py2neo. Other Statement works fine.
"

```
MATCH (own:Typea {hash:"a"})
MATCH (prev:Typea {hash:"b"}) - [c:CRED] -> (o:Typeb{index:0})
CREATE (o) - [s:SPAN] -> (own)
```

"
My database crashes with this java error:" gc overhead limit exceeded".
When i search the nodes manualy i get a MATCH
Any Sugestions?

Best Regards
Frank

Comment: can you share the profile output of your query?

Comment: how many Typea {hash:"a"} do you have, and how many Typea {hash:"b"} ? it creates a cross product between those.

Comment: Which neo4j-version do you use?

Comment: There is no Output... the query lasts until the java GC error. I have more then 300k Nodes from TypeA & 600k Nodes from TypeB.
As i said its a bulk import via py2neo,  when i execute the Query manually from the Browser everything is fine.
I Use Version 2.3.3

Answer (score 1):

*In the following, I assume that `typea` in your question should actually be `Typea`.*

To help minimize the amount of time and resources needed by the `MATCH` clauses (which might also solve the GC error), make sure you have [created indexes](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/#_using_indexes):

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Typea(hash);
CREATE INDEX ON :Typeb(index);
```

[UPDATED]

Also, it is possible that you are simply trying to create a very large number of relationships. This query will show you how many relationships you would be attempting to create:

```
MATCH (own:Typea {hash:"a"}), (:Typea {hash:"b"})-[:CRED]->(o:Typeb{index:0})
RETURN COUNT(*);
```

If the result is a very large number, you can iteratively invoke the following query (which creates just 1000 `CRED` relationships at a time) until the query returns a value less than 1000:

```
MATCH (own:Typea {hash:"a"}), (:Typea {hash:"b"})-[:CRED]->(o:Typeb{index:0})
WHERE NOT (o)-[:SPAN]->(own)
WITH o, own
LIMIT 1000
CREATE (o)-[:SPAN]->(own)
RETURN COUNT(*);
```

You can adjust the `1000` limit as appropriate.

Comment: yes your assumtion is right. I have indexes on those attributes.
When i seach manuelly the response time is fast.
I think the Problem must be in the created relationship.

Comment: Thanks, i checked your Query. The count is 1 and per definition it only can be o. The Attribut hash is uniqe. Each TypeA got n TypeB relationships which are unique with their index.
i created indexes via py2neo :" self.graph.schema.create_uniqueness_constraint('TypeA','hash')"